# Parametric (Poisson) Bootstrap

Tags: poisson-distribution, bootstrap, nonparametric, variability

I am trying to estimate population size and I am trying to assess its variability. If the only data I have is on frequencies of encounters and that I know that this frequency follows a Poisson distribution, how would I perform it? I understand the intuition behind bootstrap however I don't get how parametric bootstrap works. In my case, do I "unpack" my frequencies i.e. if I have f(1)=100 and f(2)=9 then are 100x 1 and 9x 2 my data?

Comment: Sounds like you are rather interested in simulation study than bootstrap, aren't you?